# Xvfb alternative for Mac server?

Tags: mac-osx-server

I need to run an applescript that uses Finder; however, I have to run it as a user connected via ssh. So there's no UI. And the script fails with -10810 error when there's no UI.

Is there any alternative for X11's Xvfb that I could use for Mac server 10.6 to fake a display and make the script work?

Cheers!

Tomas

Edit: To explain the problem more precisely - the script works if there's a user logged in with UI (e.g., when the user that uses ssh to run the script is also logged in via VNC). However, when I only log in  using ssh, the error appears. Which leads me to believe that the script needs UI to be able to use Finder.

So I guess running X11 and Xvfb on the server won't really help, because it won't allow me to run the script  anyway (I need to start Finder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just the Finder, AppleScript is really intended to control programs running within an Aqua UI session; trying to use it from a pure command-line environment (or even X11) seems doomed to failure.  If you're in a command-line environment, I'd use a shell script if at all possible -- there are commands available to do pretty much anything the Finder can do.

Answer (score 10):

Xvfb is not "Linux's", it's X11.

Mac OS X includes X11 support, called [**XQuartz** (aka **X11.app**)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_(application)), installed with the system by default since version 10.5. It includes Xvfb (`/usr/X11/bin/xvfb`).

EDIT: Now, that you explained better what you need, it's more clear. What you want is headless setup, to run GUI apps on that you need to either setup [**VNC server**](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2010/08/13/setting-up-the-vnc-server-in-mac-os-x-10-6/) or use [**Apple Remote Desktop**](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/).

Comment: You're right, I haven't explained myself correctly. Anyway, I think this won't really help - the problem is that there must be a user logged in with UI (i.e., not using ssh), otherwise the script fails. And X11 won't allow me to run finder or will it?

Comment: As of this writing, xvfb is no longer installed by default on OSX.